# Execute program when screensaver starts

Tags: linux, unix, screensaver

Is it possible, on Linux, to execute a program when the screensaver starts without using 3rd party tools?

For example:

I have a script that will run a who command and log the output to a file.
I want this script to execute when I leave my computer and the screensaver starts, how would I do this without using third party software?

Answer (score 1):

From the [XScreenSaver Faq](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#watch):

> How do I run a particular program when the screen blanks/unblanks?
>
> You can do that using **xscreensaver-command -watch**.

Explanation and example from the [manual](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html):

[image: -watch]

Comment: Credit to user [ST34M](http://superuser.com/users/531324/st34m) for finding this link.  It was posted as a link-only answer that was deleted in the LQ Post review queue before I could finish editing it.

Comment: This is awesome, I've been searching for an answer to this question for days. Would there also be a way to tell how long it's been idle?

Comment: @Ekult3k: Click on the Manual link in the answer and scroll to **-time**.  That gets you pretty close.